# Change left outer join on SAP Universe Design Tools

Tags: sap

I need to create a report with SAP Universe Design Tool but when I try to construct a LEFT JOIN between tables, SAP automatically create a LEFT OUTER JOIN when it executes the query in Web Rich Client.

Is it possible to force SAP to build a query just with a LEFT JOIN so it does not create blank lines in the report?

Comment: [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/3270427)

Comment: Thanks for that, however I know the diference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT OURT JOIN, but in this case SAP automatically create with LEFT OUTER JOIN and I need to use LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: There is no difference, OUTER is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTER clause is optional, you'll find a good answer in this SO question:

[LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/3270427)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T1 (id int, name varchar(10));
> CREATE TABLE T2 (id int, name varchar(10));
> INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, 'OneT1'),(2, 'TwoT1'),(3, 'ThreeT1');
> INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2, 'TwoT2'),(5, 'FiveT2'),(6, 'SixT2');
>
> SELECT    *
> FROM      T1
> LEFT JOIN T2
> ON        T1.id = T2.id;
>
>
> SELECT     *
> FROM       T1
> LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
> ON         T1.id = T2.id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    |   id | name 
> -: | :------ | ---: | :----
>  1 | OneT1   | null | null 
>  2 | TwoT1   |    2 | TwoT2
>  3 | ThreeT1 | null | null 
>
> id | name    |   id | name 
> -: | :------ | ---: | :----
>  1 | OneT1   | null | null 
>  2 | TwoT1   |    2 | TwoT2
>  3 | ThreeT1 | null | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c9fdbcfd4df9e25d7d4e98f2a0d408b8)*